# Unity without panels

Tags: unity, 12.10, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn’t load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

today I rebooted my laptop after several days of activity (meaning I don't know which updates were installed, although I supposed I can look it up). However, now when I log into my account, I can only see the background. I don't think the window manager has crashed, as I can open a terminal with window decorations with the right mouse-button. If I select Cinnamon or Gnome Classic, everything boots up correctly. 3D rendering is also still active because of the output from glxinfo. I have reinstalled ubuntu-desktop, unity and the nvidia-driver my laptop requires, but to no avail. Removing the configuration files also didn't help. Is there any way I can reinstall unity and get it back to Ubuntu's default behavior?